# Can you temporarily copy a Google Cloud image file in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

For a project, I'm trying to get an uploaded image file, stored in a bucket. I'm trying to have Python save a copy temporarily, just to perform a few tasks on this file (read, decode and give the decoded file back as JSON). After this is done, the temp file needs to be deleted.

I'm using Python 3.8, if that helps at all.

If you want some snippets of what I tried, I'm happy to provide :)

#edit

So far, I tried just downloading the file from the bucket, which works. But I can't seem to figure out how to temporarily save it to just decode (I got an API that will decode the image and get data from that file). This is the code for downloading

```
def download_file_from_bucket(blob_name, file_path, bucket_name):
    try:
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            storage_client.download_blob_to_file(blob, f)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False


bucket_name = 'white-cards-with-qr'
download_file_from_bucket('My first Blob Image', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file2.jpg'), bucket_name)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done! Added the code snippet of just downloading the file back locally. However, it needs to be stored just temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

for object store in cloud environment, you can sign your object to give access for ones who don't have account for that object, you may read  [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for google cloud

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for replying so quicky :) I don't per se need random users to access the file. I'd need to store it in the Cloud, retrieve that file for decoding purposes, and once that is done, the file can stay in the Cloud, but may be removed locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library. This is a really basic snippet. You can also name the file or read it after writing it.

```
import tempfile
  
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
  
try:
    temp.write(blob)
finally:
    temp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is part of the function, right? Also, when I give 'blob' in the 'temp.write' call, it says I can't have a Blob for this :/

Comment: I am not sure but you might need to decode base64 before trying to store it. You can use the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) library. something like this `base64.b64decode` I am not sure though. Hopefully someone with more knowledge comes

Comment: Yea, I've looked into it. It's a step I still need to take. However, it's the plan to compress an image file (uploaded by a user's phone) to a base64 and first save it to Google Cloud to save memory.